# Finding height profile of region from DEM

Tags: dem, elevation

I'm trying to work out how to obtain a height profile of a region (a county) from a 50m DEM. I have seen height / elevation profiles for regions created before but don't know how to do it and have had no luck with google. I can clip the region I want against the DEM, but don't understand how to extract the elevation data. I am using QGIS 3.10.4 with Grass and am mostly a beginner.

Comment: QGIS Tutorial: How to create Elevation Profile in QGIS https://youtu.be/acb0-NcUXM8 In QGIS 3.26, there is a newer tool: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/jvdkwast_exploring-the-new-elevation-profile-tool-activity-6962701344092610560-7Qd-/?trk=public_profile_like_view&originalSubdomain=be  , so I would upadate the installation.

Comment: Thank you so much Babel